# How to watch for changes to specific fields in MongoDB change stream with Spring Data Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, changestream

According to the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/an-introduction-to-change-streams) of the mongodb changestream, I can watch for updates on specific fields on the collecttion:

```
const changeStream = collection.watch(
[{
  $match: {
    $and: [
      { "updateDescription.updatedFields.a": { $exists: true } },
      { operationType: "update" }
    ]
  }
}],
{
  fullDocument: "updateLookup"
}
);
```

I would like to know, how to achieve the same thing with spring data mongodb reactive.

When I build a change stream with

```
Flux<ChangeStreamEvent<TestObject>> changeStream = 
mongoTemplate.changeStream(
        newAggregation(
            match(
                where("operationType").is("update")
                    .and("updateDescription").exists(true)
            )
        ),
        TestObject.class,
        ChangeStreamOptions.empty(),
        "testObject"
    );
```

I get all updates. A log of one of these change events looks like:

```
ChangeStreamEvent {
raw=ChangeStreamDocument{
    resumeToken={ "_data" : { "$binary" : "glsU9sYAAAATRmRfaWQAZFsU9sayZFockO0phgBaEATGaP42X4VI+4SrTyscwRtsBA==", "$type" : "00" } },
    namespace=test.testObject, 
    fullDocument=Document{{_id=5b14f6c6b2645a1c90ed2986, a=a, b=b, _class=com.example.demo.TestObject}}, 
    documentKey={ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5b14f6c6b2645a1c90ed2986" } }, 
    clusterTime=null, 
    operationType=OperationType{value='update'}, 
    updateDescription=UpdateDescription{removedFields=[], updatedFields={ "b" : "b" }}}, 
    targetType=class com.example.demo.TestObject
    }
```

However, when I change the filter to

```
newAggregation(
            match(
                where("operationType").is("update")
                    .and("updateDescription.updatedFields").exists(true)
            )
        )
```

or

```
newAggregation(
            match(
                where("operationType").is("update")
                    .and("updateDescription.updatedFields.b").exists(true)
            )
        )
```

I get not change events. So here is the question: how can I define the Criteria to match updates on **updatedField.b**?

A sample Document from the collection is:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b14f049b2645a4a24b33df1"),
  "a" : "va",
  "b" : "vb",
  "_class" : "com.example.demo.TestObject"
}
```

The example with the first "working" filter can be downloaded at:
[my test github repo](https://github.com/kloetzsch/mongodb-changestreams)

Comment: can you show a sample document

Comment: added a sample document

Comment: This looks correct. Do you have a more complete example of a listing? i.e Watching the change stream then modifying the document but the change does not occur. Are you certain you are actually modifying the document? Note that if you attempt to `$set` to the same value that is already present, then that is not actually a modification. You should basically get a response to confirm `nModified` and then expect the change stream event to fire and the filter condition to catch it. The only concern here is the `class type` on the aggregation. I would advise `Document` here and nothing specific

Comment: added a link to my github repo

Comment: This looks like a bug. I have  raised the bug and put more information here. Have a look. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1996